# How to establish custom message passing from AWS Ubuntu Virtual Machine to local PC

Tags: c++, amazon-web-services, sockets, amazon-ec2

I am trying to set up a simple client-server system for message passing, using a local PC and a cloud virtual machine (Ubuntu 16) hosted by AWS. It's quite basic right now and will be extended using e.g. protobuf, but right now it's about creating a basic working example before I start integrating the communication scheme into my actual program.

The 'server' waits for a request from the 'client', and will then send the data to the client. The client is given the IP address of the server on startup.

If I run the server part on my AWS virtual machine and the client part on my local PC, everything works perfect, the data is transferred. However, it does not work the other way round, I cannot reach my local PC from the AWS virtual machine. I'm pretty sure AWS security groups are correct, since it works with the server running in the virtual machine. Also the IP of the local machine should be correct, since when running the server on the virtual machine, it output the IP of the client that requested the data.

I searched before in some forums, and I figured out it seems generally more complicated to reach the local PC from the AWS virtual machine. However, I didn't find a solution to my problem, and I assume it must be possible to send data from a cloud virtual machine to a local PC...

Thanks for any help!

```
***** Client side *****

-- call client with IP of server as arg --

#define PORT "3490" // the port client will be connecting to

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sockfd, numbytes;  
    unsigned char buf[MAXDATASIZE];
    struct addrinfo hints, *servinfo, *p;
    int rv;
    char s[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;

    if ((rv = getaddrinfo(argv[1], PORT, &hints, &servinfo)) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(rv));
        return 1;
    }

    // loop through all the results and connect to the first we can
    for(p = servinfo; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next) {
        if ((sockfd = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype,
                p->ai_protocol)) == -1) {
            continue;
        }

        if (connect(sockfd, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen) == -1) {
            close(sockfd);
            continue;
        }

        break;
    }

    inet_ntop(p->ai_family, get_in_addr((struct sockaddr *)p->ai_addr), s, sizeof s);
    printf("client: connecting to %s\n", s);

    freeaddrinfo(servinfo);

    if ((numbytes = recv(sockfd, buf, MAXDATASIZE-1, 0)) == -1) {
        exit(1);
    }

    //deserialize and output data -- omitted

    return 0;
}

***** Server side *****

int main(void)
{
    srand (time(NULL));

    mydata md0; //data structure that will be sent
    //write members of md0 -- omitted

    unsigned char buf[MAXDATASIZE],*ptr;
    ptr = Serialize_mydata(buf,&md0);

    int sockfd, new_fd;  // listen on sock_fd, new connection on new_fd
    struct addrinfo hints, *servinfo, *p;
    struct sockaddr_storage their_addr; // connector's address information
    socklen_t sin_size;
    struct sigaction sa;
    int yes=1;
    char s[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
    int rv;

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE; // use my IP

    if ((rv = getaddrinfo(NULL, PORT, &hints, &servinfo)) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(rv));
        return 1;
    }

    // loop through all the results and bind to the first we can
    for(p = servinfo; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next) {

        if ((sockfd = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype,p->ai_protocol)) == -1) {
            perror("server: socket");
            continue;
        }

        if (setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes, sizeof(int)) == -1) {
            exit(1);
        }

        if (bind(sockfd, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen) == -1) {
            close(sockfd);
            continue;
        }

        break;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(servinfo); // all done with this structure

    if (listen(sockfd, BACKLOG) == -1) {
        exit(1);
    }

    sa.sa_handler = sigchld_handler; // reap all dead processes
    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    sa.sa_flags = SA_RESTART;
    if (sigaction(SIGCHLD, &sa, NULL) == -1) {
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("server: waiting for connections...\n");

    while(1) {  // main accept() loop
        sin_size = sizeof their_addr;
        new_fd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&their_addr, &sin_size);
        if (new_fd == -1) {
            continue;
        }

        inet_ntop(their_addr.ss_family, get_in_addr((struct sockaddr *)&their_addr), s, sizeof s);
        printf("server: got connection from %s\n", s);

        if (!fork()) { // this is the child process
            close(sockfd); // child doesn't need the listener

                if (send(new_fd, buf, ptr - buf, 0) == -1)
            close(new_fd);
            exit(0);
        }
        close(new_fd);  // parent doesn't need this
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does your local PC have a public IP address or a local one behind NAT or a firewall?

Comment: It's a local one, there is a NAT. The IP address that the Virtual Machine reports when the client past on my machine is also different than the on that is displayed on my machine. However, I am using the IP address that the Virtual Machine sees.